# Problema al redireccionar desde el controllador

Tags: php, mvc, poo

Al registrar un usuario envio y recibo desde el modelo en la siguiente funcion:

```
$respuesta=Datos::RegistroUsuarioModel($datosusuarios,"usuarios");

    if($respuesta == "success"){
        header("location.index.php?action=ok");
            }
            else{
                header("location:index.php");
            }
```

al registrar el usuario exitosamente entra en success, pero me manda el siguiente error:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\coffee\controller\controller.php:63) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\coffee\controller\controller.php on line 121

esta es mi linea 63:

```
echo '<option value="'.$item['id_pais'].'">'.$item['PaisNombre'].'</option>';
```

y esta es la linea 121:

```
header("location.index.php?action=ok");
```

Ya he leído en todos los foros acerca del problema y no he conseguido solución

Comment: Puede ser por varias causas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php

Comment: Al parecer es el punto entre `location` y `ìndex.php` usa `:`

Comment: El problema (independientemente de que el código esté mal en la línea 121) es que no se pueden cambiar los valores de la cabecera una vez se ha escrito algo en la página. Si buscas ["headers already sent" en Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=headers+already+sent), verás que ese mismo problema ya se ha planteado múltiples veces y que hay respuestas que te servirán (el código será diferente, pero la esencia del problema y de la solución será la misma).

Answer (score 2):

El aviso de

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\coffee\controller\controller.php:63) in C:\xampp\htdocs\coffee\controller\controller.php on line 121

Te llega por que estás enviando información extra o cambiando la información que se envía en los headers de la respuesta HTTP cuando ya enviaste información previa de contenido. En el caso muy específico de tu código es por que estás **enviando tags de html en esa línea 63** y después estás enviando nuevos headers en:

```
header("location.index.php?action=ok");
```

Revisa por que estas imprimiendo en pantalla ese echo de la linea 63 del archivo controller.php,

También el header que estas enviando esta mal escrito, cuando intentas cambiar un header como regla general se debe de escribir la variable con la primer letra de cada palabra con mayúscula si hay mas palabras en la variable se separa con "-" y para separar la variable del valor se usa un signo de ":" seguido de un espacio. Al tratar de cambiar la variable Location se debe de poner la variable con toda la URL incluido el protocolo, de la siguiente forma:

```
header("Location: http://localhost/index.php?action=ok");
```

Puedes ver la documentación del header en http://php.net/manual/es/function.header.php

Como tip adicional para sacar el nombre del servidor que estas usando puedes obtenerlo con $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']